# Cakephp redirecting not work perfectly

Tags: cakephp-2.3

In my website which page is shown before logout I surprisingly find that same page after login. But I want to get home page after every time login.
   I have already tried to solve it but unfortunately I don't get any way. Please someone help me.

Answer (score 0):

In the AppController

```
   public function beforeFilter( )
{
    $this->Auth->autoRedirect   =   false;
    $this->Auth->loginRedirect =array('controller'=>'controllerName','action'=>'actionName');
}
```